# How to select value in dropdown based on objects property value - select and angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

I have a product which has a category, and while editing product I would like to display current category in dropdown ofcourse. And if user wants to change category in dropdown it is ok, but on load I would like to show selected current product's value.

Here is my html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-xs-3">Products category:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <select id="mainGroupSelectEdit" class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"
            data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" name="mainGroupSelectEdit" required (change)="filterSubById(article.groupId)" [(ngModel)]="article.groupId">
      <option [value]="helperService.IsItEmptyGuid()"  [selected]="isDefaultSelected()">-/-</option>
      <option [value]="group.id" *ngFor="let group of mainGroups" [selected]="group.id==='a0e25215-a60e-4444-b6ac-4521b7de4b37'">{{group.title}}</option>
    </select>
{{article.mainGroup.id}}
  </div>
</div>
```

When I run my app and open this form, as you can see I put `{{article.mainGroup.id}}` <- it's binded article to check is there id of category, and when I open form it looks like this:

[image]

So obliviously `{{article.mainGroup.id}}` holds a value, but I can not force `<select>` to display that value as selected...

Any help would be awesome, thanks a lot !

EDIT:
It's doing nothing, just selecting -/- if product has no group because then article.mainGroup.id would be empty guid..

```
 isDefaultSelected() {
    return this._globalHelperService.isEmptyGuid(this.article.mainGroup.id);
  }
```

EDIT 2: By following Pranay Rana example, here is what I did :

1.) Select article
2.) Open modal
3.) Image when modal is opened:

[image]

As you can see, value is there, but nothing is selected in a modal.
Here is original code, not only img:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-xs-3">Group:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <select touch-enter-directive [ref]="ref" [nextFocusElement]="articleSubGroup" id="mainGroupSelectEdit" class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"
                data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" name="mainGroupSelectEdit" required (change)="filterSubById(article.groupId)" [(ngModel)]="article.mainGroup.id">
          <option [ngValue]="null">-/-</option>
          <option [ngValue]="group.id" *ngFor="let group of mainGroups">{{group.title}}</option>
        </select>
      {{article.mainGroup.id}}
     </div>
</div>
```

Probably select2 is making an issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what does `isDefaultSelected()` returns.

Comment: dropdown in html doesnt have multiple select

Comment: can you share code at stackbiz

Comment: I assume that `isDefaultSelected` returns true at some point, so that is the reason for the wrong behavior.

Comment: provided answer try out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this

```
   <select id="mainGroupSelectEdit" class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"
            data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" name="mainGroupSelectEdit" required (change)="filterSubById(article.groupId)" [(ngModel)]="article.groupId">
      <option [ngValue]="null" >-/-</option>
      <option [ngValue]="group.id" *ngFor="let group of mainGroups">{{group.title}}</option>
    </select>
```

In angular `[select]` is not needed it will select option based on id value you pass as `[(ngModel)] to select element`,also no need of `emptyguid` if your value is `null` then default option will get selected

Comment: I will try this in a second, but can you explain me please why do I need ngValue instead of value?

Comment: @billy_56 - check this : https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/65run4/select_option_using_value_vs_ngvalue/

Comment: if I use ngValue I realized that my dropdown ui is not working as expected, when I choose a value from a dropdown it's not closing it's staying opened like that

Comment: @billy_56 - if possible provide code at stackbiz i will have look

Comment: ok I will try to post code there, and can I bind object to ngModel like instead of article.groupId to write article.mainGroup.Id (mainGroup is property of type Group which has own id)